# How to add link in the marker in the map?

Tags: jsp, google-maps-api-3, geolocation, google-maps-markers, geocoding

I want to add the link to the marker in the map

Here is my code

```
 function findAddress(getLati,getLongi) {
       var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(getLati, getLongi);
    geocoder.geocode( { 'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) 

                    { // and, if everything is ok                     
                     var addrLocation = results[0].formatted_address;                   
                     document.getElementById('lat').value = getLati;
                     document.getElementById('lng').value = getLongi;
                     var addrMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                                             position: latlng,
                                                             map: map,
                                                             title: results[0].formatted_address
                                                             });

                     google.maps.event.addListener(addrMarker, 'click', function() {                                            
                                                   var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({                                                                                            });
                                                   infowindow.open(map,addrMarker);
                                                   infos.push(infowindow);
                                                   });                     
                    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                                   content: '<font style="color:#000;">' + results[0].formatted_address + '</font>'
                                                   });
                     infowindow.open(map,addrMarker);
                     infos.push(infowindow);
                     }
                     else
                     {
                     alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
                     }
                     });
}
```

I want to add the link to redirect the marker.
Can anyone help me with this?? Also I want to add link with the markers in map

Answer (score 0):

You can add a info window to your marker. When user click on your marker, an info window will open up, which you can add the link you want user to go to.

```
 var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
      '<div id="siteNotice">'+
      '</div>'+
          '<p>Attribution:

      Uluru, <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru&oldid=297882194">'+
      'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru</a> '+
      '</div>'+
      '</div>';

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: contentString
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: uluru,
    map: map,
    title: 'Uluru (Ayers Rock)'
  });
  marker.addListener('click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });
}
```